# First Order Logic Domain

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I studied that in First Order Logic the domain is a set.

In math, a set is defined as a group of elements. But must these elements be numbers ?

Is is possible to have a set **S** = {'1',"John","11.1"} ?

If yes , is it possible to use the domain **S** in first order logic ?

Comment: Yes; the *domain* of an *interpretation* is a "suitable" colelction or set of elements. If we are interpreting a f-o language for *arithmetic*, the domain will be "made of" numbers. If we interpret "traditional syllogism" (All men are mortal; Socrtaes is a man,...), the domain will include human beings.

Comment: I guess you don't want the quotes in specifying the set -- your intention is to have e.g. 1 and John as members, not their names!

Comment: If you have set theory available (you use the word "set"), you could write $\forall a: [a \in S \implies \cdots$. This way, you can have multiple domains of quantification e.g. $\forall a \forall b:[ a\in S \land b\in T \implies \cdots$ or $\forall a\in S: \forall b \in T:\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible to have a set $\mathbf{S} = \{1,\text{John}, 11.1\}$.

And it is possible to use $\mathbf{S}$ as the domain of the interpretation of some language in first order logic. This means that the (universally or existentially) quantified variables in a formula of such a language range over the element of $\mathbf{S}$. For instance, given a formula $\forall x P(x)$ (for some predicate symbol $P$), if the domain of the interpretation is $\mathbf{S}$, this means that $1$, John and $11.1$ have the property described by $P$.